# Windows 7 64Bit USB 2 Drivers/Devices install Fails

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, drivers

Every USB2 device on Windows 7 64Bit system can't install drivers.

My keyboard, Mouse, Soundcard(External) are all under Unknown Devices in the Device Manger. (Code 28).

USB3 is working fine except the USB3 HUB also needs to install a driver for it's USB2 compatibility. This one also can't get installed and hangs with Code28.

I also got an USB2 Wifi stick, which works on other win7 from scratch, but there is a newer driver available and if i install it the device works normally.

Cleaning the Upper und Lower Filters also got no changing. Uninstalled KIS but also no changing.

I have no System Restore Point. USB Devices are working normally (same PC) with my other Systems (XP+Ubuntu).

Comment: Fixed by copying all USB related drivers from another Windows 7 Installation to the defective Installation. In this case usb.inf usb.pnf usbstor.inf usbstor.pnf gone missing. Propably because of a defective SSD.

The drivers can be found in Windows/INF.

Comment: Awesome, nice find. I had to copy all but the usbstor.pnf.